# Multi container application

Tags: r, django, docker, docker-compose

I have to create a dockerized web application.
In my idea, I would like to create 3 containers:

- A Python Django container that can query a container that contains an R-script.
- An R container
- A Postgres database container.

My question is this: how can I query the R container from the Django container?
More specifically, how can I call from a Django view a script running into a separate R container?

Thank you for your support.

Comment: Stack overflow is about specific programming issues. Please specify your question

Comment: How can I call from a Django view a script running into a separate R container?

Comment: Put the R code behind a REST API e.g. using https://www.rplumber.io/